# 'Expression' does not contain a definition for 'Parameter'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make an expression func like in this example:
https://www.roundthecode.com/dotnet/entity-framework/using-linq-expressions-to-build-dynamic-queries-in-entity-framework

```
using DZBC.Application.DTO;
using DZBC.Domain;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DZBC.Infrastructure.Expression
{
    public partial class Expression : ExpressionBase<CompanyReadDTO>
    {
        public override IQueryable<Company> GetExampleQuery(DzbcDbContext context)
        {
            var expression = GetExpression(context);

            // Store the filter as a dynamic query.
            return context.Companies.Where(expression);
        }

        public override Expression<Func<Company, bool>> GetExpression(DzbcDbContext context, string name)
        {
 
            // Example of Query we will eventually run:
            // _dzbcDbContext.CompanyProfiles.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(name));

            var cParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Company), "c"); // c =>

            var cCompanyNameProperty = Expression.Property(cParameter, "Name"); // c.Name
  


        }
    }
}
```

But I get the 'Expression' does not contain a definition for 'Parameter' or for 'Property' errors. Even though I have the `using System.Linq.Expressions;`

And I'm using .net core 6 so it should be fine. The potential fix prompt suggests to generate those emthodes myself, but that's not what I want. I want to use the libray methodes.

[image]

Could not find anything online about this specific error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `c => c.Name.Contains(name)` is already an expression. Are you trying to implement full text search by executing a LIKE on all columns? The resulting condition, `c.Name like '%whatever%'` will be very inefficient because it can't use *any* index. This will end up scanning all rows in the table

Comment: If you want to search all (or multiple) columns consider [using full text indexes and queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver16). You can specify multiple columns in an FTS expression. You can use FTS functions like CONTAINS and FREETEXT through [DbFunctions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-6.0)

Comment: I'm trying to build something where I can build different expressions dynamically (like in the example link), I was just practicing with a simple one. Later ofc I'd want to add && || expressions, but first I need to get this library to work at least.

Comment: LINQ is already dynamic in the sense that expressions are created at runtime. You can chain different `Where` calls after a query. Creating an entire expression that can be translated to SQL is harder though. Using a library like [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) makes this a lot easier and handles the fact that entities are DbSet<> instances, not just IQueryables. It also allows you to easily create more complex expressions by combining simpler ones. The resulting code is a lot cleaner than the linked example

Comment: You are confusing the compiler naming your class like the one in the framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different `Expression` classes and they are clashing

- `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`
- `DZBC.Infrastructure.Expression.Expression`

you also have a namespace named `Expression` which confuses the compiler even more. It is recommended to rename the namespace (use plural for example) to resolve this conflict.

If you have to have both expression types in scope, the use a type alias to refer to one of them. For example

```
using LinqExpr = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression
```

Then you can refer to `LinqExpr.Parameter()` and so on.

Comment: That was it haha!